# 7z subprocess.Popen FileNotFoundError in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, compression, jupyter, popen

In my  Windows command prompt I'm using `7z x test.zip  -r -y -o*` to successfuly unzip my file.

I try this in python with :

```
def extractfiles(zipname):
    system = subprocess.Popen(['7z', 'x', zipname,'-r','-y','-o*'])
    return(system.communicate())
os.chdir('directory_with_my_test_file')
extractfiles('test.zip')
```

But receive this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-7a976fc4b8be> in <module>
      1 import subprocess
      2 cmd = ['7z', 'x', zipname,'-r','-y','-o*']
----> 3 sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      4 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pyTorch_fast07\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    727                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    728                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 729                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    730         except:
    731             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pyTorch_fast07\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1015                                          env,

       1016                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
    -> 1017                                          startupinfo)
       1018             finally:
       1019                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: try with : system = subprocess.Popen(['7z', 'x', zipname,'-r','-y','-o*'],cwd="directory_with_my_test_file")

Comment: this gives me the same error

Comment: and if you try with shell=True?...

Comment: output: (None, None), and no unzipping

Comment: I mean  : system = subprocess.Popen('your command zip/7z',shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,cwd='your path')

Comment: output: (b'',
 b"'7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n")... I tried reinstalling 7z on my virtualenv, seems to work in the virtualenv command prompt

Comment: finally got it working..switching 7z out with r'C:....7z.exe' did the trick, thanks for the help!

Comment: As an aside, are you unable to use a Python solution for this? I’m not familiar with the 7z cli options, do you just need to unzip a zip file?

Comment: good question, have been using zipfile for batch unzipping of large zipped directories and kept running into issues: files zipped on mac would crash the zipfile unzip when they hit _MACOSX folders..some files would unzip but would be missing many of the files, switching to 7zip from now on

Comment: @user3470496 great!!!